# Django Query: join a table 2 times

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I have 2 tables:

- Product(id, name)
- Attribute(id, product_id, name, value)

**How can I join the table "Attribute" 2 times when searching products? They must be in one query because of paging later.**

An example: Search products which must have 2 attributes - one for `name=att1, value=value1` and another for `name=att2, value=value2`.

---

Source Code:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    product_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False)

class Attribute(models.Model):
    attribute_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, null=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False)
```

A query that not working:

```
Product.objects.select_related().filter('attribute__name': 'n1', 'attribute__value':'v1').filter('attribute__name': 'n2', 'attribute__value':'v2')
```

Comment: Post the code for your models.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid: just updated with code.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to join them 2 times. You can create a model with ForignKey then get the set of relate attribute

For example :

you create model like this

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Attribute(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    value = models.IntegerField()
```

You can get product item by call

```
item = Product.objects.get(id=xxx)
```

Then get all list of attribute relate to this item

```
from django.db.models import Q

attr = item.attribute_set.filter(Q(name='name1') | Q(name='name2'))
```

Comment: I need to filter products that must have the attributes ("name=att1,value=value1" and "name=att2,value=value2"). In your answer, all products are returned.

Comment: There is Q objects that allow to complex lookups. I will edit the answer to query only name1 and name2 attribute

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this:

```
p = Product.objects.get(pk=1)
filtered = p.attribute_set.filter(name__in=['n1','n2'],value__in=['v1','v2'])
```